# initial configuration of minicom, to save the output of minicom into a file

Tags: linux, serial-port

my OS is LINUX , i configured mini com serial port and i am getting data from the interfaced board continuously,
please provide me the procedure to save the output of mini com in to a file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't save the output of minicom into a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334150/cant-save-the-output-of-minicom-into-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

See [minicom(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom):

`minicom -C` *capturefile*